# Does a playbook call a number of plays?

Tags: ansible

We have started to write some Ansible scripts and are wondering how to structure out code. 
The problem we are trying to answer is...  what is a play vs playbook vs roles
currently we have

```
-group_vars/...(a bunch of group vars)
-Playbooks/java/java_stack.yml
                java_app.yml

-roles/java_roles/...(a bunch of roles used in the two plays above).
```

I was under the impression that there is another level that we could call. (a playbook). where it is a group of plays. So we could call from one playbook, a number of plays. 
Exmaple playbook. (install java with apps). 
This would run `playbooks/java/java_stack.yml` once and then run `java_app`, say 3 times (with different parameters) to install what is needed.

Or is this something that really isn't designed in ansible and are playbooks just a group of roles and tasks.

Answer (score 14):

A playbook in Ansible is the yaml file that you use when you run `ansible-playbook file.yml`

A playbook is structured like so:

```
---
- name: play 1
  hosts: all
  become: true
  pre_tasks:
  - name: do something before roles
    debug: msg="this is run before a role"
  roles:
  - install_role

- name: play 2
  hosts: group2
  roles:
  - config_role
```

A Playbook is a list of plays. It can contain a single play, or many.

A Play is a list of tasks and roles that should be run. A Play can also define vars that should be used for that play.

A Role is an organizational unit for tasks, vars, files, etc. Instead of having to list all of your tasks for a play directly in the playbook, you can reference a role, which contains tasks, vars, files, templates, and handlers in one nice, portable package.